# how to generate a scrolling list from the selected item from a scrolling list

Tags: javascript, perl

I was tried to build a form. There is a scrolling list generated by perl CGI and the items will be extracted and processed by perl CGI as well. However, I am stuck at further improved this form. Because for some items, there are also different ways to process them. What I want is that when a user click on a item of this scrolling list, it will generate another scrolling list or pop-up list for more selections. And the user can further select from this scrolling list or pop-up list and the selection will be extracted and processed by Perl.
I know this client-side work may have to be done by javascript. I know some javascript, at least can understand most of the code written in it, but I have no experience in writing them to process such event driven condition and combine the results with Perl CGI.

Could someone tell me how to do this using javascript? Thank you.
Xiaokuan

For Example:
I have a scrolling list by Perl CGI:

```
print scrolling_list(-name=>"animals",-values=>["dog","cat"],-labels=>{dog=>'dog',cat=>'cat'});

#This will generate a scrolling list of "dog" and "cat". What I want is when a user click on dog to make a selection, this scrolling list will generate another scrolling list or pop-up list such as:

print popup_menu(-name=>"action", -values=>['walking','training'],-labels=>{walking=>'walking the dog',training=>'training the dog'});
```

Comment: You're asking [too broadly](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) - you describe a desire, not a question. Do you know the basics of HTML and DOM manipulation? What have you tried, which part are you having problems with, where are you stuck without the help of others? (I did not downvote this question, but at least you should get an explanation for downvotes and the lack of answers.)

Comment: Thank you daxim. I updated original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice prescribes that forms *must* be accessible *without JavaScript*. So instead of generating a new form fragment when the user selects something, we generate *all* form fragments *in advance* and use JavaScript to hide them, and when the user selects something, it becomes unhidden.

```
use CGI qw();
my $c = CGI->new;
print
    $c->header('text/html'),
    $c->start_html(
        -script => [
            { -src => 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', },
            q<
                function hide_all () {
                    jQuery('#dog,#cat').hide();
                }
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    hide_all();
                    jQuery('select[name="animals"]').click( function(e) {
                        hide_all();
                        jQuery('#' + jQuery(e["target"]).val()).show();
                    });
                });
            >,
        ],
    ),
    $c->scrolling_list(
        -name   => 'animals',
        -values => [qw(dog cat)],
        -labels => {dog => 'the dog', cat => 'the cat'},
    ),
    $c->popup_menu(
        -id     => 'dog',
        -name   => 'action1',
        -values => [qw(walking training)],
        -labels => {walking => 'walking the dog', training => 'training the dog'},
    ),
    $c->popup_menu(
        -id     => 'cat',
        -name   => 'action2',
        -values => [qw(playing feeding)],
        -labels => {playing => 'playing with the cat', feeding => 'feeding the cat'},
    ),
;
```

Comment: Thank you daxim, I just tested you code chunk, it works like a charm; and I can extract the selection from the second popup menu as well. It seems JQuery is an important tool to know, I will make an effort to learn it.Thank you again.